# segue with protocol/delegate data passing called twice

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I want to set up some data from a tableViewCell before a segue. In my table extension I overload didSelectRowAt to set that data up. This is based on advice I read to trigger the segue there with:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "itemSelected", sender: cell)
```

My segue from the table row selection action in the storyboard is firing and flow of execution is reaching this controller's *prepare for: segue* **before** **didSelectRowAt** is firing. The result is that my **performSegue** (and the preceding work to set it up) is handled after an initial attempt, and it looks like the destination view controller is loaded twice in quick succession -- the second one being correct.

I'm wondering how I can leave the segue defined, but remove it from the selection action on the storyboard.

ps: I know that **shouldPerformSegue** could be used to abort the automatic one that comes first .. but it seems like it would be even better to not have to abort it in the first place.

Comment: segue is attached to the cell or the VC ?

Comment: to the cell's selection action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach the segue to the cell selection action , the navigation occurs twice one from the attach , and the other from `performSegue` code inside `didSelectRowAt` , so you need to attach the segue to the VC itself

Comment: thats cool -- would I change the sender to self instead of cell, in the code in the OP ? (just verifying) ... also, more importantly, how would I do more than one identifier in this way?

Comment: that depends on what you want to get inside **prepareForSegue** , I think sending the cell makes more sense so you can know the pressed one , self is accessible anyway inside **prepareForSegue**

Comment: thank you this has worked. I wasnt clear how I would name it since it would only be one arrow, but you can still name each with distinct identifiers

Comment: you can create an array of identifiers and navigate according to **arrOfIndifiers[indexPath.row]**

Answer (score 0):

Your segue is likely attached directly to the tableViewCell on the storyboard. When you attach it to the cell like that, Xcode is essentially attaching *performSegue* to the *didSelectRowAt* method on that cell.

To fix this, you'll want the segue to come from the view controller itself. That will define the segue without attaching it to any actions. Then, you'll be able to call it programmatically.

Comment: the sender is just used to pass data to the prepareForSegue method. This could be the data you're using to initialize the next viewController, or it could be nil. It's just a way to pass whatever data you'll need inside that function (notice the type of sender is "Any?").